# Cross-compile library (poker-eval) for iOS

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, poker

I am trying to cross compile the c-library of poker-eval (from http://gna.org/cookbook/?group=pokersource) for iOS, i.e. for use on arm7 architecture.

I am following the compile instructions of http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/ to chose the settings and environment variables for configure.

So far so good, it is able to succesfully configure and build most of the source files until it exits with error:

> make[1]: ./mktab_basic: Bad CPU type in executable

Apparently poker-eval builds some executables that generate table (source) files that are necessary for a complete build. As I am compiling everything for arm7 architecture it is clear that I cannot run these programs on my computer. I am not sure if I could first generate those files with a normal build and then include them in the arm7 build. I fear that they are generated at compile time because they are processor dependant.
So before I try to hack deep into the makefile and configure (I have little experience doing so) I'd like to hear if anybody has an idea how to overcome this?

I hope I made my problem clear.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The last time I looked at the project, the generated code was for small lookup tables.  I don't think you should have any problem compiling/using the tables generated from one arch on another.